# Get the Build configuration

Tags: powershell, configuration, build, teamcity

How in teamcity i can get the Build configuration ID via powershell. i have to run tests with different values if bt1 than vlue will change to "true" if bt2 than "false"  this my script which will  make changes

```
Param ($hiddenfunctionality)
Write-Host "Updating C:\Program Files\\Empower\Web\Web.config"
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xd = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
 $file = resolve-path("C:\Program Files\\Empower\Web\web\Web.config")
 $xd.load($file)
   $xd.SelectNodes("configuration/appSettings/add[@key='opentext.empower.site.enableHiddenFunctionality']").Item(0).SetAttribute('value', $hiddenfunctionality)
$xd.Save( $file)
Write-Host "Done"
```

Comment: What is going wrong with the script you've posted?

Comment: when i configure the build step in teamcity with $true or $false to give it for $hiddenfunctionality it doesn't work and field value is empty

Comment: This looks correct.  I suspect your XPath is bad but can't tell for sure since I don't have an example of this XML file.  Can you show the relevant section of XML in this post?  For instance, is the attribute you're searching for called `key` and then you are setting another attribute called value on that same element?